# How to write in one regexp two regexps where the second one cleans the leftover from the first one?

Tags: regex

I have this case as example, where I need to transform the left side to the right side (filtering out everything with `KO`):

`item n1: KO, diff item 2: OK, item number3: OK, subitem 4: KO` -> `diff item 2: OK, item number3: OK`

with a potential varying number of `itemX`.

At the moment I am applying 2 regexps to get to the right side:
`s/[a-z0-9\s]*:\sKO,?\s?//g`which takes to -> `diff item 2: OK, item number3: OK,` 
and finally `s/,?\s?$//` to remove the final `,` .

Is there a way to have only one regexp instead of 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^[a-z0-9\s]*:\sKO,?\s?|,\s[a-z0-9\s]*:\sKO`

https://regex101.com/r/eiKTAr/1

Comment: I am using this solution :) as it is the simplest and passes all my tests.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex for searchL:

```bash
(?:, *(?=(?:[a-z0-9 ]+: *KO[, ]*)+$)|\b)[a-z0-9 ]+: *KO[, ]*
```

and replace this with empty string.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sjXCNS/3)

```js
const s = `item n1: KO, diff item 2: OK, item number3: OK, subitem 4: KO,`;

const re = /(?:, *(?=(?:[a-z0-9 ]+: *KO[, ]*)+$)|\b)[a-z0-9 ]+: *KO[, ]*/gm;

console.log( s.replace(re, '') );
//=> diff item 2: OK, item number3: OK
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `(?=(?:[a-z0-9 ]+: *KO[, ]*)+$)`: Match `,` followed by 0 or more spaces if 1+ `KO` items are last items in the list (using a lookahead assertion)
  - `|`: OR
  - `\b`: Word boundary
- `)`: End non-capture group
- `[a-z0-9 ]+`: Match 1+ letters, numbers or spaces
- `:`: Match a `:`
  - `*`: Match 0 or more spaces
- `KO`: Match `KO`
- `[, ]*`: Match 0 or more comma or spaces

Comment: Doesn't work with `diff item 0: OK, item n1: KO, diff item 2: OK, item number3: OK, subitem 4: KO` (result: `diff item 0: OKdiff item 2: OK, item number3: OK`).

Comment: True, as InSync said it will return `diff item 0: OKdiff item 2: OK, item number3: OK`

Comment: @Randomize: Did updated regex work for you?

Comment: It does not work for a case like `item1: KO, item 2: OK, item n3: KO, item4: KO, item5: KO` as it returns `item 2: OK, `

Comment: @Randomize: Made a minor update to take care of that case well, please check.

Comment: Jfyi that selected answer leaves a trailing comma for `item n1: KO, diff item 2: OK, item number3: OK, subitem 4: KO,` as input.

Answer (score 1):

There is no language tagged, so depending on the regex flavor, you might use an [if clause](https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html) and test for the existence of group 1.

Note that `\s` also matches a newline.

```
(?:(^)|,\s)(?:[a-z0-9\s]+:\sKO(?(1),\s))+\b
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternatives

  - `(^)` Capture the start of the string in group 1
  - `|` Or
  - `,\s` Match a comma followed by a whitespace char
- `)` Close the non capture group
- `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole part

  - `[a-z0-9\s]+:\sKO` Match 1+ times any of the listed in the character class followed by `:` a whitespace char and the word `KO`
  - `(?(1),\s)` If group 1 exists, match a comma and a whitespace char
- `)+` Close the non capture group and repeat 1+ times to match all occurrences
- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mKrYUx/1).

Comment: Thank you great solution! My fav as it uses `KO` text only once.